# Read from a JSON file inside a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a directory named **Resources** in my WPF project and I have a **Settings.json** inside that directory.
I want to read content from that file. 
In file settings I have **Build Action -> Embedded Resource** and **Copy to Output Directory -> Copy Always**
And I read the file like this :

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"/Resources/Settings.json"))
```

And I get the following exception :

> {"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Resources\Settings.json'."}

How can I make this read the file in that directory? Thanks

Comment: What type of app? In a console app this will get you to the \bin directory: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: @Icryder WPF application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"/Resources/Settings.json"))
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Application' does not contain a definition for 'StartupPath'

Comment: I guess this is valid only for Windows Forms applications.

Comment: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for WPF apps.

Comment: How would it be in a ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 11):

Since you've got your Build Action set to Embedded Resource, you probably want to use the [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.

For example:

```
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyCompany.Namespace.Settings.json"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Answer (score 1):

For .Net Core project add these lines to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Resources\**\*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```