# How can I pass a Settings.json file as a StreamReader parameter

Tags: c#, json, parameters

I have a method that I need to pass a json file into StreamReader to use it as a parameter. The json file is in my solution as Settings.json file. How can I make a reference to Settings.json to use that as the parameter for the StreamReader?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

See code below

```
public void method()
{

    var HTTPClient = new HttpClient();
    var config = new Configuration();

    var parser = new FluentCommandLineParser<SessionIDArguments>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Settings.json))
    {
        dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());
        config.Settings = new Settings(results);
    }

    GetSessionResponse GSR = new GetSessionResponse(config.Settings, HTTPClient);
    GSR.GetSessionId("147393074553169");

}
```

Comment: If you set the Settings.json file property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer", it will end up in the Release or Debug folder along with the executable so you can just open it as if from the current directory.

Comment: Or put the file inside App_Data and then 
**use string appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
);
string filePath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, "test.txt");**

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Read from a JSON file inside a project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25081766).